# How to define different dependencies for different product flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-build

I am converting one of my apps to Gradle and would like to use the new build flavor features to have a paid and a free ad based flavor.

I want only the ad based version to depend on the admob SDK.

My build file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    productFlavors {
        Pro {
            packageName "de.janusz.journeyman.zinsrechner.pro"
        }
        Free { 
            dependencies {

            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Is there a way to configure the dependency in the free product flavor to have its own libs folder that is merged with the main libs folder that contains general libraries for both flavors?

If this is possible how would I define this folder?

Comment: visit this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860659/multi-flavor-app-based-on-multi-flavor-library-in-android-gradle/24910671#24910671

Answer (score 222, accepted):

To define a flavor specific dependency you can use `proCompile` instead of `compile` in your dependency section. When you run gradle properties you get an overview of automatic created configurations.

The correct build file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    productFlavors {
        pro {
            packageName "de.janusz.journeyman.zinsrechner.pro"
        }
        free { }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    freeCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this and getting this error, `Error:(28, 0) Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'glassCompile()'!` (The flavor I'm trying to add a dependency to is "glass".)

Comment: Ahh, looks like you have to move the `dependencies` block below the `android` block. How intuitive.

Comment: Note that the `xxxCompile` closures Gradle generates will not work if the flavor name starts with a capital letter.

Comment: "packageName" should be "applicationId"

Comment: How do you handle not calling the Ad classes?

Comment: @JarettMillard and note the difference! "compile" it's without flavors but when it's for flavors it's "Compile" with capital (or camelCase)

Comment: @JaredBurrows put different versions of the classes that call the Ad classes in the different flavors. Probably it's better to have a single central class where you call those.

Comment: this does work but for release builds i'm getting error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.applinks.FacebookAppLinkResolver$1
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)` i think proguard is creating this issue.

Comment: What if I want to remove the dependency for release builds, but leave it for debug builds?

Comment: I've just upgraded to Andorid Studio 3.0 and I noticed that `dependencies` section no longer needs to be below `android` section in build.gradle - I was able to stipulate `debugCompile` even though my dependencies are listed above the android section. @Tiago use `debugCompile`

Comment: Okay but what if I want to compile play-services dependency **instead of** support library dependency in `free` flavor?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere I'm on AS 3.3 BETA 04 and you *still need* to put it below; we have 3 variants (debug/release/qa) and i was trying to use `qaImplementation 'some.dependency:1.0'` and it didn't work until I literally cut/paste the entire `android {`  section (which includes `buildTypes` above `dependencies { `. `debugImplementation` and `releaseImplementation` worked, but if you define custom ones, they apparently must appear above. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 49):

Fast forward to mid-2018. You will need to add `flavorDimensions`.

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "dimensionName"
    productFlavors {
        pro {
            dimension "dimensionName"
        }
        free {
            dimension "dimensionName"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    freeImplementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
}
```

Also, take note:

> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>   'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of 2018. For
>   more information see:
>   http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

Comment: Do you know how to do it with buildVariants instead? like proDebugImplementation.

Comment: please add a separate question for this. link it here in the comment section. please add complete details of what you are trying to achieve. :)

Answer (score 16):

Simple:

```
dependencies {

    ....
    ....

    gradle.startParameter.getTaskNames().each { task ->
        if(task.contains("free")) {
             implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
        }
    }

    ....
    ....
}
```

or just:

```
FreeImplementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
```

Answer (score 14):

You need to manually add configuration for each flavor. Example

```
configurations {
    proCompile
    freeCompile
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'

    proCompile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    freeCompile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'
}
```

Comment: How to go on from there? How to activate the different configurations? Does this apply to the Android build only? Is it possible to that with non-Android builds?

Answer (score 11):

**Edit:** I recommend using one of the other techniques!

An alternative to the accepted answer is this:

```
    ext {
        flavorType = ""
    }


    gradle.startParameter.getTaskNames().each { task ->

        if(task.contains("flavor1")){
            flavorType = "flavor1"
        } else if (task.contains("flavor2")){
            flavorType = "flavor2"
        } else {
            flavorType = "flavor3"
        }

    }

 if(flavorType == 'flavor1' || flavorType == 'flavor2') {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    }
```

Comment: that does not allow you to build multiple flavours at once, which is kind of a deal breaker for most of us. Furthermore it might not work well with android studio too

Comment: this is in the dependencies block?

Comment: Is this block in dependecy ?

Comment: hmm... doesn't scale well with 10 or 50 flavors does it?

Comment: @Ewoks  I hava to make lots of flavors, do you have any better idea?

Answer (score 10):

If you use Gradle with Kotlin (build.gradle.kts), dependencies for custom flavors can be added as follows:

```
dependencies {
    "freeImplementation"("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0")
}
```

Comment: It works but why is it a valid answer? Any source?

Comment: @VaiTon It is defined as an overloaded operator for String in DependencyHandlerScope.kt, looks as follows:
`operator fun String.invoke(dependencyNotation: Any): Dependency? = dependencies.add(this, dependencyNotation)`

Answer (score 0):

**This way will work in multi-module projects**

create a build gradle file (for example build_flavor_config.gradle) and define your config in it like this

```
android {
    flavorDimensions 'resource_type'
    productFlavors {
        create("flavor1") {
            dimension 'resource_type'
            versionName "$app_version_name - flavor1"
        }
        create("flavor2") {
            dimension 'resource_type'
            versionName "$app_version_name - flavor2"
        }
    }
}
```

and apply this gradle file for every module that you want for example app module or a feature module like this:

```
apply from: rootProject.file("build_flavor_config.gradle")
```

after sync project you can access to specific of implementation of each flavor like this:

```
flavor1Implementation("flavor1Library")
flavor2Implementation("flavor2Library")
```