# Android Multiple Flavors with Multiple Build Types

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

We have a project with multiple flavors and each flavor has 3 different buildTypes: debug, QA and release.

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {}

    flavor2 {}

    flavor3 {}   
    }

buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }

    qa {
        applicationIdSuffix ".qa"

    }

    release {
   ..
    }
```

But for each flavor and buildType we need different library dependency. For example:

```
compile 'baseUrl:myLibrary:1.0.0:flavor1Release@aar'
compile 'baseUrl:myLibrary:1.0.0:flavor1Qa@aar'
...
compile 'baseUrl:myLibrary:1.0.0:flavor3Qa@aar'
```

Can we add these dependencies using a Groovy script?

Comment: You should use flavorDimenions and variantFilters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60010971/5279996 GL

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can define specific dependency per buildType like this

```
debugCompile 'baseUrl:myLibrary:1.0.0:debugLib@aar'
releaseCompile 'baseUrl:myLibrary:1.0.0:release:Lib@aar'
```

- compile: main application
- androidTestCompile: test application
- debugCompile: debug Build Type
- releaseCompile: release Build Type.

> Because it’s not possible to build an APK that does not have an
>   associated Build Type, the APK is always configured with two (or more)
>   configurations: compile and Compile. Creating a new Build
>   Type automatically creates a new configuration based on its name.

It also seems to be working just fine with flavor as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18213259/2776572) (*but not with flavorDimensions*)

Doing it for a variant (buildType+Flavor) seems a bit more work. Otherwise you could define your library as a real library project and use a syntax like this

> To create a dependency on another published artifact, you need to
>   specify which one to use:

```
dependencies {
    flavor1Compile project(path: ':lib1', configuration: 'flavor1Release')
    flavor2Compile project(path: ':lib1', configuration: 'flavor2Release')
}
```

From: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

1. If you want to create multiple **build type** in our single project.So you need follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66315794/12134511 I am use following code working is fine so don't go anywhere just follow link.

I hope this code help full for you.

Comment: This link is helpfull for me. Thanks for your support.