# Product flavors in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-productflavors

I can not get product flavours working. I have this gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    defaultConfig {
      minSdkVersion 14
      targetSdkVersion 24
      compileSdkVersion 27
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
      }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    flavorDimensions "dim1", "dim2", "dim3"
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            dimension "dim1"
            applicationId "com.example.dim1.app"
        }
        flavor3 {
            dimension "dim2"
            applicationId "com.example.dim2.app"
        }
        flavor3 {
            dimension "dim3"
            applicationId "com.example.dim3.app"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        flavor1 {
          java.srcDirs = ["W:/android-studio-projects/sharedid/app/src/main/java/"]
          manifest.srcFile "W:/android-studio-projects/sharedid/app/src/example1/AndroidManifest.xml"
          assets.srcDirs = ["W:/android-studio-projects/sharedid/app/src/example1/assets/"]
          resources.srcDirs = ["W:/android-studio-projects/sharedid/app/src/main/res/", "W:/android-studio-projects/sharedid/app/src/example1/res/"]
        }
        flavor2 {
          java.srcDirs = ["W:/android-studio-projects/sharedid/app/src/main/java/"]
          manifest.srcFile "W:/android-studio-projects/sharedid/app/src/example2/AndroidManifest.xml"
          assets.srcDirs = ["W:/android-studio-projects/sharedid/app/src/example2/assets/"]
          resources.srcDirs = ["W:/android-studio-projects/sharedid/app/src/main/res/", "W:/android-studio-projects/sharedid/app/src/example2/res/"]
        }
        flavor3 {
          java.srcDirs = ["W:/android-studio-projects/sharedid/app/src/main/java/"]
          manifest.srcFile "W:/android-studio-projects/sharedid/app/src/example3/AndroidManifest.xml"
          assets.srcDirs = ["W:/android-studio-projects/sharedid/app/src/example3/assets/"]
          resources.srcDirs = ["W:/android-studio-projects/sharedid/app/src/main/res/", "W:/android-studio-projects/sharedid/app/src/example3/res/"]
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    api 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.8'

}
```

...

When I got to **"Build | Select variant"** I can only select

Module:*app*
Build Variant:*flavor1Flavor2Flavor3Debug*,*flavor1Flavor2Flavor3Release*

I would have liked to get

- the following build variants: *flavor1Debug*,*flavor2Debug*,*flavor3Debug*,*flavor1Release*,*flavor2Release*,*flavor3Release*

I have tried "File | Sync project with gradle file"

...

I get this error

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot read packageName from
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

I have tried to both

- have no such file (hoping it would take the product flavor one?)
- have the "main" manifest only define shared stuff between all product flavors

Comment: The exception says it can't read packageName from AndroidManifest.xml. What manifest files in your flavors actually exist?

Comment: But why do you need 3 dimensions? Have you tried to define just one and use that one?

Comment: Also you are asking about debug variants. You're only defining one buildType: release. Add another one for debug. It can be empty.

Comment: You probably need only 1 dimension

Comment: @Cata I have changed it to a single now - no difference in results though

Comment: @SofiSoftwareLLC I have added it now - no difference in results though

Comment: @SofiSoftwareLLC each flavor has each own complete manifest. (In the past I would simply manually copy assets, resources, manifest etc. into "main" folder) --- however - bear in mind that the error message acually states it is trying o read the manifest file in the "main" folder

Comment: Share the link to your full project if possible.

Comment: Hello dear don't miss the following link https://stackoverflow.com/a/66315794/12134511 your problem fully satisfy. I have using following link code.It's code working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just try like below,

```
 flavorDimensions "dim1"
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        dimension "dim1"
        applicationId "com.example.dim1.app"
    }
    flavor3 {
        dimension "dim1"
        applicationId "com.example.dim2.app"
    }
    flavor3 {
        dimension "dim1"
        applicationId "com.example.dim3.app"
    }
}
```

For more details about build variant [see this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

Comment: This still gives the same error - but thanks for the links

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two unrelated problems :

- Currently you have 2 build types (the automatically created `debug` and `release`) and 3 dimensions (`dim1`, `dim2` and `dim3`), each one having 1 variant (`flavor1` for `dim1`, `flavor2` for `dim2`, ...)
  this gives at most :

  2 * 1 * 1 * 1 = 2 combinations

  You should switch to 2 build types and 1 dimension (say `dim1`) having 3 variants (`flavor1`, `flaver2` and `flavor3`) to have :

  2 * 3 = 6 apks
- You should have a main manifest. Unlike other resources the manifest is not simply overriden but merged from multiple sources (see [Merge Multiple Manifest Files](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge) for more details).

  It should at least contains a package name (possibly different from the final applicationId(s)) as explained by this note from [Configure Product Flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors) :

> **Note** : You still need to specify a package name using the **package** attribute
>   in the **main/** manifest file. You must also use that package name in
>   your source code to refer to the R class, or resolve any relative
>   activity or service registration. This allows you to use **applicationId**
>   to give each product flavor a unique ID for packaging and
>   distribution, without having to change your source code.

Answer (score 0):

> I would have liked to get
>
> the following build variants:
>   flavor1Debug,flavor2Debug,flavor3Debug,flavor1Release,flavor2Release,flavor3Release

For this, you need to define the **same dimension** for all flavors.

> I get this error
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot read packageName from
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

You get this error because the path is not reachable.

Just think, how can app find ***W:*** when it is running?

So, you need to use a relative path here.

Also from official documentation (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#configure-sourcesets):

> If you have sources that are not organized into the default source set
>   file structure that Gradle expects, as described above in the section
>   about creating source sets, you can use the sourceSets block to change
>   where Gradle looks to gather files for each component of a source set.
>   You don't need to relocate the files; **you only need to provide Gradle
>   with the path(s), relative to the module-level build.gradle file**,
>   where Gradle should expect to find files for each source set component