# How to deal with different jar in different flavors of an Android project?

Tags: android, gradle

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196974/how-to-define-different-dependencies-for-different-product-flavors/18213259#18213259) explain how to include different dependencies in different productFlavors of the project.

I did that, but now how can I handle my own code calling code from a jar not included in one flavor of my project ?

**example**

admob.jar have a `Aaa.class` and is only included in the *free* flavor. When I compile *pro* flavor, it fails because `Aaa.class` is not in the classpath.

I don't wan't use reflection (it's inefficient and time-consuming).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196974/how-to-define-different-dependencies-for-different-product-flavors/18213259#18213259), you can use flavors to include different dependencies, BUT you can also include specific src files in a flavor:

Create directories `src/pro/java/` and `src/free/java/` .

All source files in src/pro/java will be compiled only in the "pro" flavor using the dependencies defined for the "pro" flavor.

All source files in src/free/java will be compiled only in the "free" flavor using the dependencies defined for the "free" flavor.

Now assume that you have a java source file `SomeClass.java` calling some code in admob.jar. You can the the following :

1. put `SomeClass.java` in `src/free/java/SomeClass.java`
2. duplicate `SomeClass.java` in `src/pro/java/SomeClass.java`
3. remove all calls to admob.jar from `src/pro/java/SomeClass.java`
4. if you did it properly : both flavors of your project should compile

Tip: try to organize your code in such a way that duplicated class are reduced to the strict minimum.

Comment: thanks for you answer, it is a solution, but it make code structure seems disorderly, I am reading grandle use guide, find if have any machine like annotation, pass the class compiled.

Comment: sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      exclude 'some/unwanted/package/**'
    }
  }
}
we can exclude packages and files which we donot need, then can compiled.