# Different dependency sets for each build type

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have 2 jar files that one of them is for release and the other one is for debug.

I dont want to play them to export a apk each time in Android Studio. How can i automate it?
I am all open for examples snippets and more.

BTW I also need different assets files too.

Thanks

Comment: check this question -> http://stackoverflow.com/q/18196974/4018207

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it in many ways.

You can use 2 different folders, one for each buildType (or flavor).

```
libA
   debug.jar
libB
   release.jar
```

Then:

```
dubugCompile fileTree(dir: 'libA', include: ['*.jar'])
releaseCompile fileTree(dir: 'libB', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Or you can use somenthing like:

```
debugCompile files('libs/first.jar')
releaseCompile files('libs/second.jar')
```

For the assets resources (or resources/java file), just use the buildType folder. This is the structure:

```
module
   src
     debug
       assets
       java
       res
     release
       assets
       java
       res
     main
       assets
       java
       res
```

Comment: Does compiler cut the unused jars? For example i build apk using release build type then is debug jar going to put into apk? Btw, i dont have proguard yet.

Comment: Using different folders with dubugCompile and releaseCompile the jar is not included in the apk.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti what if we have a few custom build types, for example ```staging``` and ```beta```. Their custom configurations don't seem to be working, ```stagingCompile``` and ```betaCompile```