# In Gradle apply different dependcy version to one flavor

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build

I know how to add a dependency to one specific flavor as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196974/how-to-define-different-dependencies-for-different-product-flavors) and [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-how-to-implement-productflavor-dependent-dependencies-with-gradle)!

But on my current setup I need 1 flavor to use 1 version of the library and all the other flavors to use a different version. Something like:

```
// this gets applied to all flavors expect "otherFlavor"
compile 'com.awesome.library:lib:1.0'

// this gets applied only to "otherFlavor
otherFlavorCompile 'com.awesome.library:lib:1.1'
```

if I try as shown on this code I keep getting:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processotherFlavorDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.awesome.library'

is that possible without having to list every.single.flavor?

Thanks !