# What is the most efficient way to support builds with different minimum API Levels where sections of code require different APIs

Tags: android, android-api-levels

I have a project where I need to make new builds once a month or so with incremental changes. The previous minimum supported API level was 19 and some devices were at that level so it was necessary to support it.

A new dependency that is being implemented (by the client) requires a new minimum API of 21 and there will be a large quantity of code inserted to support it.

The core of the issue here is that moving forward I still need to support a build a month (ish), I need to support those older API level 19 devices, and I need to support the new code for API level 21 or higher devices.

I have been thinking of simply changing the minimum API level, removing the new dependency, commenting out the new code, and making a build for API 19 devices and then undoing that process to make the new build for API 21+ devices, but that seems awfully inefficient.

My question therefore is, **what is the most efficient way to create multiple builds that have to support different API levels without going through and commenting out code and removing dependencies?**

Comment: Use flavors https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors

Comment: Flavors would be a great idea if I wanted to change certain sections of code to just augment them, but in this case I need to remove dependencies and remove code that is depending on said library; I don't know of a way to make flavors do that. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196974/how-to-define-different-dependencies-for-different-product-flavors

Comment: Also see https://android.jlelse.eu/product-flavors-for-android-library-d3b2d240fca2